# How can I create a route and use a path to enter the first step in a mulistep form with the Wicked gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-5.2, wicked-gem

I have tried using the Wicked gem 3 different times over the past 8 years. Each time, I have given up for the same reason. I'm trying again, because if I understand it, I think it will be perfect for my use case.

My main problem is that I don't understand how to actually begin the wizard. With the example used in the gem, it is an `after_registration` event that already has an associated `user` object. That is not helpful, nor do I think that example would be helpful in the majority of use cases.

There is another example about building a `Product` in multiple steps. However, the author fails to adequately explain the routing. From https://github.com/zombocom/wicked/wiki/Building-Partial-Objects-Step-by-Step:

```
Since Wicked uses our :id parameter we will need to have a route that also includes :product_id for instance /products/:product_id/build/:id. This is one way to generate that route:

resources :products do
  resources :build, controller: 'products/build'
end

This also means to get to the create action we don't have a product_id yet so we can either create this object in another controller and redirect to the wizard, or we can use a route with a placeholder product_id such as [POST] /products/building/build in order to hit this create action.
```

OK, I have no idea what the second part of the sentence means as far as `placeholder product_id` and that route name of `/products/building/build`. I spent 2 hours trying that and just moved on to a blank create form.

`...we can either create this object in another controller and redirect to the wizard`

That's what I'm trying to do upon successful save of the @product object.

`redirect_to product_by_interchange_path(@product, :step1)`

That doesn't work. `raise InvalidStepError if the_step.nil?` Says my step is nil. It's not.

`redirect_to product_by_interchange_path(@product, step: :step1)`

Same thing.

`redirect_to product_by_interchange_path(:step1)`

That's an exact mirror of the 8 year old example app. But of course @product isn't in a session variable like `current_user` is, so in this case the error is that there's no Product with an id of :step1.

Please help! I am missing something very, very basic here but I very much need to persist.

Comment: IT would be very helpful to see your controller actions and routes in a coherent form. otherwise it is very difficult to debug your issue. wicked is fairly straightforward - this problem should be easily solvable

Answer (score 1):

OK I have finally figured this out. Here's what I did:

1. First of all, I changed my controller back to a plain old `ApplicationController` and used the include `include Wicked::Wizard`. I don't know if that did anything, but the newer example was laid out like the old.
2. I was really screwed up by `:id`. I'm thinking `:id` is generally my object ID. I had a set_product private method in my controller, and it was failing. When I finally figured out that `:id` was the actual step itself, that led me to change my path in the redirect.
3. I changed the redirect from `product_by_interchange_path(@product, :select_vehicle)` to `product_by_interchange_path(:select_vehicle, product_id: @product.id)`
4. I got rid of my `set_product`. Just while I was trying to eliminate confusion.
5. I changed my finder calls in the wizard to use `:product_id` instead of `:id`.

It works now. I still don't understand how I could have stubbed out a route with a placeholder product_id, that's still a mystery. But this is fine and it works.